# Unable to get the value of the combo set to the viewmodel

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-combobox

I have implemented the cascading feature of kendo drop down. While trying to save the information, I am not able to  get the value of the combo in my viewmodel. If I comment the name attribute, I do get the value however I need the name attribute for the cascading feature to work. I was trying a workaround using jquery to set the model value but getting errors. Could somebody tell me how to fix this issue.

**Sales Organisation Combo**

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.CountryCode)
    .Name("SalesOrganisation")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
    .DataTextField("CompanyCodeCompany")
    .DataValueField("CountryCode")
    .Filter("contains")
    .MinLength(3)
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Read(read => read.Action("RequestHeader_SalesOrganisation", "Request").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
    .ServerFiltering(true)
    )

                    )
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Sales Office combo**

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SalesOffice, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.SalesOfficeID)
             //  .Name("SalesOffice")
             .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
            .DataTextField("SalesOffice")
            .DataValueField("SalesOfficeID")
            .AutoBind(false)
            .Value("")
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("RequestHeader_SalesOffice", "Request")
                        .Type(HttpVerbs.Post)
                        .Data("GetFilterOption");
                }).ServerFiltering(true)
                ).CascadeFrom("SalesOrganisation").Filter("contains")

                            )
                        </div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SalesOffice, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Javascript for cascading feature to work**

```
 function GetFilterOption() {

        return {
            id: $('#SalesOrganisation').val()
        }

    }
```

**Javascript - Trying to set the model which doesnt work**

```
function GetFilterOption() {
        var countryCode = $('#SalesOrganisation').val();
        var model = $('#SalesOrganisation').data('kendoComboBox');
        model.value = countryCode;
         return id = countryCode;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use .ComboBoxFor(), you should not use .Name().

When you use .ComboBoxFor(m => m.FieldName) then the id/name attribute will be set to "FieldName" by kendo's implementation of the Razor helper and *matches* the name of your model field.

If you then use .Name("SomeOtherFieldName"), you change the id/name attribute to "SomeOtherFieldName" and it *no longer* matches the field name of your model, which is why you no longer get the value.

What you want to do is *not* use .Name() and set up the .CascadeFrom() appropriately, i.e.

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.CountryCode)
....

@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.SalesOfficeID)
    .CascadeFrom("CountryCode")

function GetFilterOption() {
    return {
        id: $('#CountryCode').val()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that works But I have a another combo that filters based on this combo' text field. What do I do there 
    function GetFilterOption1() {

        return { id: $('[name = "SalesOrganisation"]').data("kendoComboBox").text().split('-')[0] }

    }

Comment: I did the same assigning the countrycode for the other filter option and it seems to work. Is that right way of doing

Comment: Yes, you have to refer to you inputs/elements/widgets by a single and consistent name, which is the name of your ViewModel field when you use the XXXXFor() razor helpers.

Comment: Quite a strange thing happening. What was working a couple of hours ago isnt working now. The second child combo is working. The first child combo which was working is now not working. I dont see the javascript method GetFilterOption firing.Hence when the execution breaks at the controller the parameter value is null.